# How can we use Custom Exception using Financial Force FFLIB

Tags: design-patterns, salesforce, enterprise

I am trying to create a rest service using FFLIB. I can't find any sample code for throwing custom exception.

Comment: Might worth asking on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/